# How to obtain the nim compiler version programmatically ?

Tags: nim-lang

Is there any constant variable or `proc` that allows to access the compiler version as a string or number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The version can be obtained as a string](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#NimVersion) via `system.NimVersion` (remember that `system` is implicitly imported):

```
echo NimVersion # 0.18.0
```

[You can also access its component parts](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#NimMajor) (MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH) as numbers like so:

```
echo NimMajor # 0
echo NimMinor # 18
echo NimPatch # 0
```

This makes checking versions for compatibility very easy when combined with tuples:

```
when (NimMajor, NimMinor, NimPatch) >= (0, 19, 0):
  echo "we're on at least Nim v0.19.0"
```